# How do I stop my button from failing with input in the box?

Tags: css, input

I have a button that is taking text entry in an input box and appending to a URL and redirecting.
The entire system is working, however the problem I am facing is when I enter the text and click the button nothing happens. Every time I add text, the button does nothing.

When I dont enter any information, the button takes me to the url that should have the input appended to (wihtout the appended information)

```
<div class="pen-title">
    
 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card">
      
      <form>
        
        <div class="input-container">
          <input type="#{type}" id="txt" required="required"/>
          <label for="#{label}">Password</label>
          <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
          <button id="btn"><span>Go</span></button>
        </div>
       
      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the JS:

```
 <script>
   
var nickname = document.getElementById("txt");
function redirect () {
  window.location.href = "https://theurl.com/details?info=" + nickname.value;
};
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', redirect);


  </script>
```

If I use the JS with the following button settings:
(THE FOLLOWING CODE WORKS AND IS ONLY A DEMO TO SHOW THAT THE FUNCTION IS ACTUALLY WORKING FULLY)
The code with the bug is the code above this line.

```
<div class ="input"> <input type="text" id="txt" />
    <label for="txt"> Enter Reg </label> </div>

<div class="buttons">
        
 <button class="pulse" id="btn">Pulse</button>
    
  </div>
<script>
var nickname = document.getElementById("txt");
function redirect () {
  window.location.href = "https://carservicesinreading.co.uk/check-mot-history/details?car-reg=" + nickname.value;
};
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', redirect);
</script>
```

it works first time. However the template of this set up was different css for the input box and different CSS for the button and I just cannot get it in the layout I would like.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hello, the code you are showing works. This means we cannot reproduce your error, certainly because there are missing parts of the puzzle.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Thanks, that was taken direct from W3 school which means I messed it up somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

the only thing i can see as you haven't provided much info. on the button i added type submit.see if i helps as i can see it redirects and says cannot find mot details.do you have real reg no for testing?

update:removed form tags.

```js
var nickname = document.getElementById("txt");
    function redirect() {
        window.location.href = "https://theurl.com/details?info=" + nickname.value;
    };
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', redirect);
```

```html
<div class="pen-title">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="input-container">
                    <input type="#{type}" id="txt" required="required" />
                    <label for="#{label}">Password</label>
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="button-container">
                    <button id="btn"><span>Go</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A real reg is LB51 TVW

Comment: the code that is running in your post is the code that works( the demo code that I provided to show that the script does work). The first code blocks are the codes that are not working and i need help on.

Comment: how do i create a runnable code so you can see the button that is failing?

Comment: What do mean by failing?

Comment: With the two first snippets, when you run the html you get an input box and a button.  Pressing he button does not add the input to the url like the second code snippets.

Comment: i tried it and go it to work .but i have no idea why its happening remove the form opening and closing tag..and it works

Comment: i also updated the snippet

Comment: and a suggestion. you should rewrite your html. because that seems to be the issue

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved the issue exactly spot on. Sometimes I think dipping my toe into coding was a mistake, little errors like this have me stuck!

Comment: this is my first forray into this, I copied the JS code from one website and the input field and button + css from another and butchered the two together to work. (took me a while but then realised that in some cases i just had to get the id="" to match the JS.